# Omnifaces as JBoss AS7 module

Tags: jsf, jboss, module, cdi, omnifaces

I'm trying to extract the Omnifaces library from a .war archive to JBoss module, however, there are problems with *`org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped`*. Application deploys successfully but breaks on first page load.

I've read BalusC's report on problems with .wars packaged in .ear (http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013_10_01_archive.html) but I'm not sure if it applies to this situation as well since we have only .war.

When the Omnifaces library is included in .war's lib folder via Maven as a compile time dependency everything works flawlessly:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Setting the dependency to provided scope, creating a JBoss module and appending the jboss-deployment structure to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.omnifaces" export="true" meta-inf="import"/>
            <!-- i tried multiple export and meta-inf combinations -->
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.omnifaces">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="omnifaces-1.7.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javaee.api"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" />
    </dependencies>

</module>
```

Is it possible to use Omnifaces this way, as a JBoss module?

Answer (score 0):

OmniFaces is as being a JSF utility library designed as WAR module, not as EAR or appserver module.